# How Apache Solr works with Django 1.5?

Tags: python, django, apache, solr, django-haystack

I am new on Django framework. So please help me work with solr and Django.
I am trying with some tutorial available on different site but all worked with older versions of Django and Apache Solr those are not compatible with new versions.

Answer (score 1):

Django and Apache Solr have no relation with each other.
You can use django like you would use normally, and use `pysolr` or `sunburnt` python module to fetch/write data to SOLR.
I would recommend `pysolr` for its simplicity.

Comment: yes, i am using pysolr module, but don't know how it works. I am searching for tutorial but don't find. Can you help me?